# Erro de injeção de um objeto JPA no ManagerBean no projeto web

Tags: jsf, jpa

Estou tendo um erro de injeção de um objeto JPA no ManagerBean no projeto web.

Tenho dividido em dois projetos controlados pelo maven.
No primeiro projeto chamado PerolaModel contenho as configurações
persistence.xml, as classes de conexão com o banco, a classe com as anotações jpa e a classe dao.
No segundo projeto chamado apenas Perola tenho:
O PerolaModelx.x.x.jar que obtenho via maven
o managebean e o xhtml.

Nos testes de conexão e utilização da classe entidade Feriado funciona 100% em ambos os projetos.
Porem quando a utilizo no managebeam da o erro de injeção.

Já apaguei todo repositório maven para ver se era algum conflito de dependências
Já coloquei tudo em um único projeto web 
mas o erro persiste.

[Link para arquivo com todos os dados](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=AA64DD827B73F7E2!468&authkey=!AE5VS7aqOhGwK_8&ithint=file%2C)

javax.el.ELException: /paginas/crudFeriado.xhtml: Um erro ocorreu ao realizar a inje??o de recurso no bean gerenciado feriadoMB
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:90)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:82)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:72)
    at org.primefaces.component.outputlabel.OutputLabelRenderer.encodeEnd(OutputLabelRenderer.java:113)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at br.com.transportesalvorada.controller.mb.filtro.FiltroLogin.doFilter(FiltroLogin.java:30)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Um erro ocorreu ao realizar a inje??o de recurso no bean gerenciado feriadoMB

Comment: Estive comparando um projeto antigo que funciona e notei o seguinte:
Se utilizo o hibernate 5.1.0 da o erro em questao.
Se utilizo o hibernate 4.3.8 funciona normalmente.

Isso resolve de imediato. Mas não sei se é algo que mudou no hibernate 5.1.0 ou é bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se todas as referências desse Bean estão corretas.

Sempre lembrando que são Case Sensitive.

Me parece que ele não "encontra" o bean e consequentemente não consegue fazer o injection por referência.

Comment: Estive comparando um projeto antigo que funciona e notei o seguinte:
Se utilizo o hibernate 5.1.0 da o erro em questao.
Se utilizo o hibernate 4.3.8 funciona normalmente.

Isso resolve de imediato. Mas não sei se é algo que mudou no hibernate 5.1.0 ou é bug.

Comment: Eu estava utilizando a biblioteca do hibernate erra 
O correto era este.

<dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
 <version>5.1.0.Final</version> 
 <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>